# Riddles, Riddles, Riddles Everywhere!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My Prefix is short for a 2 word phrase
>
> My Infix can be as round as a every circle
>
> My Suffix is a common preposition that consists of only 2 letters
>
> My whole can make your head dizzy

Now tell me, what am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

> Spin. Prefix is SP for Starting Point (Credit to Kevin) . Infix = Pi which is needed to calculate a circle parameters. Suffix = In which is a common preposition. And spinning around makes you dizzy!

Comment: Correct Answer mate :). Btw, Sp means starting point for the prefix

Comment: Oooh I did not know that.

Comment: Great job! +1 (I also thought of that but I couldn't find time to come back onto the site. )

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Illusion? 
>  Prefix: I'll, short for I will 
>  Infix: usi, not sure 
>  Suffix: On, a common preposition 
>  An illusion can make you dizzy

Comment: unfortunately incorrect, +1 though :)

Comment: Gonna give u a hint : ROT 13 (Guvf jbeq pbafvfgf bs bayl 4 yrggref)